# Error when setting up desktop application for MSIX packing in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I followed [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net) from official Microsoft team to use the `Windows Application Packaging Project project` in Visual Studio to generate a package for my `WPF` desktop app. A Note [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/packaging-uwp-apps#create-an-app-package-using-the-packaging-wizard) reads: `If you're packaging a desktop application, right click on the the Windows Application Packaging Project node.`. So I did just that (as shown below). But at the end of the wizard, I got the error shown at the end below:

[image]

**Remark**: My WPF project, `MyWPFProject` is a `.NET 5` project, and the Application Packaging Project project name is `WapProjTemplate1`. I'm using latest version `16.9.3` of `VS2019`

**Question**: Why the error, and how can we resolve it. As, the following figure shows, my both projects target the same platform.

[image]

> > Error: There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "C:\MyFolder\MyWPFProject\bin\x86\Debug\net5.0-windows\win-x86\MyWPFProject.dll", "x86". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project. WapProjTemplate1    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets

Comment: I encountered the same error and had to change the platform to x86 to suppress it. It's just a workaround though.

Comment: @emoacht I changed the platform to x64 and set the two values shown below in the screenshot from user @HuiLiu-MFST, to make it work. I agree it's a workaround. I would like to know how to make it work for `Any CPU`.

Comment: Fully agree. `Any CPU` should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to modify your Configuration Manager as below:

[image]
After completing the above steps, please right click your **WapProjTemplate1**, choose **Publish** on the popup and select **Create App Packages...** Then select **Release** for **Architecture** on **Select and configure packages** wizard as below:
[image]

**Update:**

On a 86-bit Windows operating system: Executables and DLL that are compiled with the Any CPU execute on the 32-bit CLR.
On a 64-bit Windows operating system: A DLL compiled with the Any CPU executes on the same CLR as the process into which it's loaded. Executables that are compiled with the Any CPU execute on the 64-bit CLR.
The Target Platform of the program and the referenced DLL should be consistent at runtime. Generally speaking, we can set the Target Platform of the program to be consistent with the deployed operating system according to actual needs and the DLL is preferably Any CPU. The special deployment environment requires special consideration.
Maybe because your project is compatible with "Any CPU" but you have a dependency on a project or DLL that is either x86 or x64. Because you have an x86 dependency, technically your project is therefore not compatible with "Any CPU".

Comment: After Right Click-->Publish-->Create App Packages, I get a dialog titled `Select Distribution Method` that has only two options: `Microsoft Store under new app name` and `SideLoading`. I don't get the screen you are showing. I'm using `VS2019 - ver 16.9.3` Community edition.

Comment: I started over with a new `WPF .NET 5` project by setting the platform to `x64`. And after following your instructions , I was able to create the MSIX bundle to deploy the app. There was one extra step that you have missed in your post. I did the following steps: Right Click on Packaging Project-->Publish-->Create App Packages-->A dialog titled `Select Distribution Method` appears where I selected SideLoading. Then the screen you showed in your post appeared, where I set the values you recommended - and it worked (thank you). I still would like to know why `Any CPU` does not work.

Comment: Hi, @ nam.I have updated my answer, you could check it.