# Can't publish MSIX package for WPF .NET 5 project, due to X86 Architecture conflict, but can publish same project using .NET Framework 4.8

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, msix

I have built a WPF project with .NET Framwork 4.8 and published it to Microsoft Store via a UWP bridge project as outlined here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net#prepare-your-application.
Basically, I had no problem following and publishing my .NET Framework project.

So, I decided to do the same with the same project as a .NET 5.0 project. However, when I select the final publish (right mouse click on the UWP project and then menu item publish - create app packages), in the resulting compilation I get the follwoing error:
There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "C:\Projects......\bin\x86\Release\net5.0-windows\win-x86....dll", "x86". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.  WapProjJHT_Inclusive    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets   2183

I have built both projects targeting any CPU and have even tried just publishing a window's x64 target with the package and Always get this same error.

Does anybody know what could be causing the problem or if there is a better way to publish an MSIX package for upload the MS store? Thanks!

Comment: It looks similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67066210/error-when-setting-up-desktop-application-for-msix-packing-in-visual-studio

Comment: Have you checked the Configuration Manager about the target platform?

Comment: Have now followed the advice given in the similar question 67066210 and have changed the target platform to 64 as shown in the solution. But now I get a new error that a json file is missing. Have tried doing a nuget restore but simply get the message that there is nothing to restore.

Comment: Here is the Error I get now: Assets file 'C:\Projects\...\...\obj\wappublish\win-x64\project.assets.json' not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file.